# Ошибка при конвертации Py файл в EXE

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller

Есть код, хочу конвертировать его в EXE. через pyinstaller. Команду использую pyinstaller --onefile main.py. В общей директории лежит json файл. Но при запуске EXE файла выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'accounts.json'
[30771] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Процесс завершен]
```

Как мне добавить этот json файл?

Comment: с CWD все нормально? Оно точно совпадает с тем где находятся данные?

Comment: Все файлы и папки лежат в одной директории

Comment: Это прекрасно но не отвечает на вопрос, CWD совпадает с папкой в которой лежат файлы? CWD - Current Working Directory.

Comment: Да все совпадает